# Video recorded in android cannot play in IOS Using HTML Video tag

Tags: ios, iphone, html5-video, webkit, mobile-webkit

**Update:**
I record **VP8** video from Android that is saved as MP4 format, which should be supported by Safari. From some research I know Opus audio format is partially supported by Safari...

- What else do I need to add while saving file (*eg:* output settings)?
- Is it because of the Opus audio format that Safari is not playing VP8 video format?

**Question**:

In my application which records the video from any device and saving in AWS server, and admin can play recorded videos from any os/ device.

After the iOS updated on Dec 14 2022, my video component is messed up, I cannot record or play video from Apple devices.

As I cannot write entire project code, I have the code in the below link

[video player code - Github](https://github.com/amran-quantum/videoplayertesting)

In the code the video src is from **AWS S3** (storage) which is recorded from Android phone, from the link below you can play the video.

[video player testing](https://amran-quantum.github.io/videoplayertesting/)

This video can be played in Mac Chrome, but not in Mac Safari, Apple Safari and Apple Chrome.

I am looking for quick solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use and don't have access to iOS or Mac Safari, so you must test this for us...

Looking at [your MP4 file](https://api.tenrol.com/uploads/videos/159_159_1652901854.mp4) in a **hex editor** I see this:

[image]

It seems you have a **WebM** file that simply has `.mp4` added to the file name. 
It is not an MP4 (there is no MPEG header/data inside these file bytes, etc). 
Your file here has `webm` in **second line** something which a real MP4 would never do. A valid MP4 usually has `ftyp` written in its **first line**.

**Possible solutions:**

**(1)** To avoid confusing some decoders (about file format) try renaming file as:

```
159_159_1652901854.webm
```

Some players will use the file **.type** extension to decide which decoder to use. If it is **file.mp4** and some player uses the MPEG decoder on those VP8 bytes then  you will get no picture or sound.

**(2)** Also try to set correct WEBM mime-type (*ie:* because it's not a `video/mp4`)

```
<video height="700" controls muted autoplay playsinline loop>
<source src="https://api.tenrol.com/uploads/videos/159_159_1652901854.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

**note:** consider testing a WebM video with no sound, to answer if Opus audio is the problem.

See if the above `<video>` tag code works on Mac Safari and iPad Safari. I think **Opus** (usually audio for OGV files) and **Vorbis** (usually audio for webM files) are **not supported on iPhone** (unless you put the audio in an MOV format, but then you lose the video part). Basically iPhone has no WebM sound.

**(3)** If all else fails then just understand the following:

- MP4 plays in all major browsers.
- MP4 contains H.264 or H.265 picture codecs, and also AAC or MP3 audio codecs.
- Browsers prefer to record in their own in-house/licensed codecs.
  (Google == WebM (VP8/9), Mozilla == OGV (Theora) and Apple == MP4 (H.264/H.265)).
- Don't use Webm (Chrome/Firefox) if you want guaranteed Safari playback of video.
- Don't use MP4/H265 (Safari) if you want guaranteed Chrome/Firefox video playback.

There is no easy solution. So your options are:

- To guarantee that you get H264/MP4 **encoded** in Chrome/Firefox browsers, then **try finding a Javascript based H.264 encoder**. Here's a [search example](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript+h.264+%22encoder%22) to start with. Then you also need an audio encoder for AAC or MP3 formats. Such a file would play in Safari.
- Or else, push for getting WebM **decoded** by Safari browser (even if without sound). This means a lot of testing. Use a tool like FFmpeg to output short 10 second test videos of WebM (at different settings) until something displays. Then you can move onto dealing with sound.

Comment: Thank you so much...This explanation is enough to find solution.. I really appreciate your effort you put to write this. Thanks again VC.One

Comment: My code is working fine from the **option 3**. I am facing issue while uploading to aws s3. for 1 min video it taking 3 mins to save.. please check this link for code explanation [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75433519/uploading-recording-file-stream-to-aws-s3-in-php-is-very-slow)

Comment: My code is working fine from the **option 3**. i commented aws s3 uploading to find root cause of time delay.. ffmpeg conversion taking more time.. please check the code attached in this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75433519/uploading-recording-file-stream-to-aws-s3-in-php-is-very-slow?noredirect=1#comment133097771_75433519) @VC.One

Answer (score 0):

The video you recorded is using the vp8 video codec which should be supported on Safari on Mac but also the opus audio codec which is not usually supported.

> Video Info for https://api.tenrol.com/uploads/videos/159_159_1652901854.mp4
>
> Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'test.mp4':
>
> Metadata:
>
> encoder : Chrome
>
> Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A>
>
> Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp (default)>
>
> Stream #0:1(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p(progressive), 1080x1920, SAR 1:1 >DAR 9:16, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)>

You can check the video format using ffprobe (https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html)

or online here (it will take a little while): https://getvideoinfo.westshoretechnology.com

You can check browser support for codecs in the browser release notes or at sites like this which are usually up to date: https://caniuse.com/opus

The Android video encoding recommendations are available online and the current recommendations at the time of writing are:

[image]

These are pretty good guides cross device at this time also - the link is here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats

Comment: Thank you...when did I research, opus audio format is partially supported by Safari, when i record video from android I am saving as mp4 format, which should be supported by safari aswell, what else I need to add while saving. and is this because of audio format safari not playing video ob vp8 format.

Comment: @Sara  I think currently opus is not supported in mp4 on safari - you can check at the link above. The most supported combination of container and codecs at this time is most likely h.264 for video, AAC for audio and mp4 container. I've added some info on recommended Android video formats which is a pretty good cross device guide also.

Comment: My code is working fine from the option 3. i commented aws s3 uploading to find root cause of time delay i see that ffmpeg conversion taking more time.. please check the code attached in this link [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75433519/uploading-recording-file-stream-to-aws-s3-in-php-is-very-slow?noredirect=1#comment133097771_75433519) @Mick